# R ggplot How to plot a bar chart with different colours inside depicting 3 differents columns from the dataframe?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am from a province which have 3 different areas.
I have a dataframe with all the days and the deaths from covid19 in whole the province. My idea its plot the data by weeks or month. The sum of these 7 days or 30 days. But I want to make the difference with 3 colours to depict the 3 different areas.

So this is my code. I can plot the total column. The 3 areas are called: alicante, valencia , castellon.

I don´t know how to do it!

```
    library(ggplot2)
library(scales)






log <- read.csv('https://dadesobertes.gva.es/es/datastore/dump/69c32771-3d18-4654-8c3c-cb423fcfa652?bom=True',stringsAsFactors = F,encoding = 'UTF-8')
colnames(log) <- c("code", "Date", "total", "hombres", "mujeres", "alicante", "castellon", "valencia", "dvinaros", "dcastellon", "dlaplana", "dsangunto", "dmalvarrosa", "dvilanova", "dlafe", "drequena", "dvalenciageneral", "dpeset", "dlaribera", "dgandia", "ddenia", "dxativa", "dalcoy", "dlamarina", "dsanjuan", "delda", "dalicantegeneral", "delchegeneral", "dorihuela", "dtorrevieja", "dmanises", "delchecrevillente" )




#log$Date <- as.Date(log$Date,

log$Date <- as.Date(log$Date,
                    "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") # tabulate all the options here






# create variables of the week and month of each observation:
log$Mes <- as.Date(cut(log$Date,
                         breaks = "month"))
log$Week <- as.Date(cut(log$Date,
                        breaks = "week",
                        start.on.monday = FALSE)) # changes weekly break point to Sunday









# graph by month:
ggplot(data = log,
       aes(Week, total, fill="Defunciones semanales")) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, # adds up all observations for the month
               geom = "bar") + 
      labs(fill = "Color", y = "") +
  #geom_text(aes(y = total,label = total), vjust=0, hjust= 0,size=4) +
  
  

  
  labs(title = "Defunciones semanales en la Comunidad Valenciana hasta el 17 de Enero",
       subtitle = "Fuente:dadesobertes.gva.es/es/dataset/covid-19-series-personas-fallecidas. ") +
  scale_x_date(
    #labels = date_format( "%B"),
    labels = date_format( "%d-%m"), 
    limits=c(as.Date("2020-03-01"), as.Date("2021-02-01")),
                          
    breaks = "1 week") + # custom x-axis labels
  
   

  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This more an issue in data wrangling than in plotting. To achieve your desired result reshape your data to long format using e.g. `tidy::pivot_longer`. Additionally set `position` to `"stack"` in `stat_summary` to stack the bars for the areas.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)


log <- read.csv("https://dadesobertes.gva.es/es/datastore/dump/69c32771-3d18-4654-8c3c-cb423fcfa652?bom=True", stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "UTF-8")
colnames(log) <- c("code", "Date", "total", "hombres", "mujeres", "alicante", "castellon", "valencia", "dvinaros", "dcastellon", "dlaplana", "dsangunto", "dmalvarrosa", "dvilanova", "dlafe", "drequena", "dvalenciageneral", "dpeset", "dlaribera", "dgandia", "ddenia", "dxativa", "dalcoy", "dlamarina", "dsanjuan", "delda", "dalicantegeneral", "delchegeneral", "dorihuela", "dtorrevieja", "dmanises", "delchecrevillente")

log$Date <- as.Date(
  log$Date,
  "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
) # tabulate all the options here

log$Mes <- as.Date(cut(log$Date,
  breaks = "month"
))
log$Week <- as.Date(cut(log$Date,
  breaks = "week",
  start.on.monday = FALSE
)) # changes weekly break point to Sunday

# select desired or needed variables and reshape to long format
log_area <- select(log, 1:2, 6:8, Mes, Week) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(code, Date, Mes, Week), names_to = "area")

# graph by month:
ggplot(
  data = log_area,
  aes(Week, value, fill = area)
) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.y = sum, # adds up all observations for the month
    geom = "bar",
    position = "stack"
  ) +
  labs(
    fill = "Color", y = "",
    title = "Defunciones semanales en la Comunidad Valenciana hasta el 17 de Enero",
    subtitle = "Fuente:dadesobertes.gva.es/es/dataset/covid-19-series-personas-fallecidas. "
  ) +
  scale_x_date(
    labels = date_format("%d-%m"),
    limits = c(as.Date("2020-03-01"), as.Date("2021-02-01")),
    breaks = "1 week"
  ) + # custom x-axis labels
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
#> Warning: `fun.y` is deprecated. Use `fun` instead.
#> Warning: Removed 87 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary).
#> Warning: Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>